# añadir clase al visitar una url

Tags: php, css, html5

estoy buscando la manera de como al visitar el inicio se quede la clase active y cuando visite las otras que se active esa clase , sin embargo estoy usando php, para llamar ese menu mediante un include

```css
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #47c9af;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  background: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li > a {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: -4px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 18px 25px 12px 25px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444444;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  margin-right: -4px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120%;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(2deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
  -moz-transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(2deg);
  -moz-transform-origin: bottom;
  transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(2deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a:after,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a:after,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover:after {
  background: #47c9af;
}
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Products</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Company</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Esta respuesta me sirvió a mí sin tener que modificar mucho mi código: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/190164/83304

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te dejo mi manera favorita de hacerlo, existen infinidad de ellas y dependiendo de lo que necesites específicamente puede que te vengan mejor otras.

```
<?php
    $menu = [
        ['uri' => '/', 'title' => 'Home'],
        ['uri' => '/products', 'title' => 'Products'],
        ['uri' => '/company', 'title' => 'Company'],
        ['uri' => '/contact', 'title' => 'Contact']
    ];
?>

<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
        <?php
            foreach($menu as $m) {
        ?>
            <li class="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == $m->uri ? 'active' : ''; ?>"><a href="<?php echo $m->uri; ?>"><?php echo $m->title; ?></a></li>
       <?php
            }
       ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Existen múltiples maneras de hacer esto (sesiones, AJAX, localstorage...) ¿La más sencilla y rápida a mi juicio? Podrías pasar junto a las redirecciones de los enlaces un parámetro por `$_GET` que determine que **item** del menú debe poseer la clase active:

**HTML**

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='/home?active=home'>Home</a></li>
   <li><a href='/products?active=products'>Products</a></li>
   <li><a href='/company?active=company'>Company</a></li>
   <li><a href='/contact?active=contact'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Luego, en cada una de esas páginas podrías recuperar el valor de "active" y dependiendo de este asignar la clase al **item** del menú que corresponda.

Yo incluiría esta comprobación en el **fichero** en el que cargues el menú, ya que es a su **HTML** al que deseamos afectar. Aunque podrías gestionar el tema de añadir la clase al **item** con Javascript.

**PHP**

```
$active = $_GET['active'];
echo '<div id="cssmenu">';
echo '<ul>';
switch ($active) {
   case 'home':
      echo '<li class="active"><a href="/home?active=home">Home</a></li>';
      echo '<li><a href="/products?active=products">Products</a></li>';
      echo '<li><a href="/company?active=company">Company</a></li>'
      echo '<li><a href="/contact?active=contact">Contact</a></li>';
      break;
   case 'products':
      echo '<li><a href="/home?active=home">Home</a></li>';
      echo '<li class="active"><a href="/products?active=products">Products</a></li>';
      echo '<li><a href="/company?active=company">Company</a></li>'
      echo '<li><a href="/contact?active=contact">Contact</a></li>';
      break;
   case 'company':
      echo '<li><a href="/home?active=home">Home</a></li>';
      echo '<li><a href="/products?active=products">Products</a></li>';
      echo '<li class="active"><a href="/company?active=company">Company</a></li>'
      echo '<li><a href="/contact?active=contact">Contact</a></li>';
      break;
   case 'contact':
      echo '<li><a href="/home?active=home">Home</a></li>';
      echo '<li><a href="/products?active=products">Products</a></li>';
      echo '<li><a href="/company?active=company">Company</a></li>'
      echo '<li class="active"><a href="/contact?active=contact">Contact</a></li>';
      break;
}

echo '</ul>';
echo '</div>';
```